# append multiple .csv files

Tags: csv, append, filenames

I have several thousand .csv files in a folder and am trying to use the cdm to append them. Each file is the same table with top header and bottom notes. For example,

```
121030_2003.csv
121030_2004.csv
...
121031_2003.csv
121031_2004.csv
...
```

I tried `copy *.csv all.csv` from cmd and I would like to add code for the resulting file to have:

1. the header reported only once at the beginning, and possibly no notes
2. an additional column, reporting the name of the source file to keep track of it.

Comment: What are your constraints? Just cmd.exe built-in commands? Any program installed with Windows? Is PowerShell okay? Or programs that you can install, such as [GOW](https://chocolatey.org/packages/Gow)? And, which version of Windows? Are the header and notes uniquely distinguishable from the data other than by being the first and last lines?

Comment: @Tom: Powershell is ok too, though my knowledge is very (and I mean very) basic. Never heard about GOW. I have Windows7. The tables are all 4 columns (A to D) wide and about 20 lines long, but not always, sometimes 19. Headers and Notes are additional texts at the top and bottom on rows. I am not 100% sure that length is the same for all of them (I have about 80,000 csv files). Inside the tables I have no information about the IDs and Years, info which is instead on the filename.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use cat in Linux.

e.g. for appending 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt to an output file 0.txt

```
cat 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt > 0.txt
```

csv files are just like txt files so it will be the same in your case, except that 'type' is used in cmd  for 'cat'.